# React Material UI - Override using withStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-with-styles

I am working on a project and leverage React Material UI and need to override the Select component's border bottom color on the focused state.  Here is what I'm using right now

```
import { Select as MuiSelect, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { BRAND_COLORS } from '../../constants/colors';

const FONT_SIZE = 20;

const Select = withStyles({
  root: {
    fontSize: FONT_SIZE,
    '&:focus': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: BRAND_COLORS.blue,
    },
  },
})(MuiSelect);

export default Select;

<Select
  native
  startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start"><FilterListIcon /></InputAdornment>}
  value={service.regionalFocus}
  onChange={(event) => this.props.changeSelectedRegionalFocus({
      providerId, serviceId: service.service_id, regionalFocus: 
event.target.value})
      }
    >
      {regionalFocus.map((region, index) => service.service_regions[region.value].length ? (
        <option key={index} value={region.value}>
          {region.label}
        </option>
      ) : null)}
    </Select>
```

I'm able to override the font size, however, the borderBottomColor is not registering.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The select component mounts an input inside it. Can you please provide how are you actually rendering the select ?

Comment: I just looked at what is being mounted and there isn't an input.  This just renders a select with the options included.

Comment: an mui input actually. please provide how are you using the select

Comment: Below is how I'm implementing the Select

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to style the `Input` that is a child of `Select`. To override `Input` props, including styling, you'll need to pass them as an override in the `inputProps` prop on `Select`.

Something like:

```
const MySelect = (props) => {
  return (
    <Select {...props} inputProps={{ classes: { underline: props.classes.inputOverride } }}
  );
};

export default withStyles({
  root: {
    fontSize: FONT_SIZE,
    '&:focus': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }
  },
  inputOverride: {
    '&:after': {
      borderBottomColor: BRAND_COLORS.blue,
    }
  }
})(MySelect);
```

The docs for `Select` and `Input` will help you here:
https://material-ui.com/api/select/
https://material-ui.com/api/input/

As well as the source code to really understand how it all works:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/d956b40539d7b724ca6026aeae96e1f42dd22331/packages/material-ui/src/Select/Select.js#L230

Comment: I gave this a shot and it didn't actually override.

Comment: thanks for bringing that to my attention. I think my syntax wasn't quite right I think. `withStyles` adds a `classes` prop to the component which you  can then use to override things. Does this get you closer?

Comment: Still not getting it to override the .MuiInput-underline:after css

Comment: I ended up fixing this by overriding it in my common styles by targeting the class and adding !important.  Not ideal however - I'd love to fix this with withStyles api